# Optimize SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(col)) var, col2 var2 FROM table WHERE col<>'X' and col2 between 'Y' and 'Z' GROUP BY var2 ORDER BY var DESC; for speed?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, mariadb

I have this query and it takes ages (about 10 min) to complete.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(column)) var, 
       column2 var2 
FROM table 
WHERE column<>'X' and 
      column2 between 'Y' and 'Z' 
GROUP BY var2 
ORDER BY var DESC
```

Any ideas how to optimize for speed? I tried with indexes but still slow. Maybe they are not set properly. Y and Z are timestamps, if it matters, and X is something that is not needed at all for this query but is in the table for it is needed for other queries from the same app. The table is very large - millions of rows, and it is yet to grow.

**Edit**: Here is the EXPLAIN result from an example:

```
    mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ip)) v, geo n from idevaff_iptracking where geo<>'XX' and stamp between '1525122000' and '1543615199' group by n order by v desc;
+------+-------------+--------------------+-------+------------------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys          | key          | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                                     |
+------+-------------+--------------------+-------+------------------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | idevaff_iptracking | range | stamp,geo,geo_stamp_ip | geo_stamp_ip | 9       | NULL | 3469323 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+--------------------+-------+------------------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table locums are as follows:

id,acct_id,ip,refer,stamp,hit_time,hit_date,src1,src2,split,sub_id,tid1,tid2,tid3,tid4,target_url,geo.

Indexes are as follows:

```
    mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM idevaff_iptracking
    -> ;
+--------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| idevaff_iptracking |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id          | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_ip         |            1 | acct_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_ip         |            2 | ip          | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | ip                 |            1 | ip          | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | stamp              |            1 | stamp       | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id            |            1 | acct_id     | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | geo                |            1 | geo         | A         |         440 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | tid1               |            1 | tid1        | A         |         276 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | tid2               |            1 | tid2        | A         |         514 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | tid3               |            1 | tid3        | A         |          34 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | tid4               |            1 | tid4        | A         |        5623 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_stamp_ip   |            1 | acct_id     | A         |         744 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_stamp_ip   |            2 | stamp       | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_stamp_ip   |            3 | ip          | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | geo_stamp_ip       |            1 | geo         | A         |       22362 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | geo_stamp_ip       |            2 | stamp       | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | geo_stamp_ip       |            3 | ip          | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid1_stamp |            1 | acct_id     | A         |         658 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid1_stamp |            2 | tid1        | A         |       11866 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid1_stamp |            3 | stamp       | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid2_stamp |            1 | acct_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid2_stamp |            2 | tid2        | A         |       18666 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid2_stamp |            3 | stamp       | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid3_stamp |            1 | acct_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid3_stamp |            2 | tid3        | A         |        1832 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid3_stamp |            3 | stamp       | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid4_stamp |            1 | acct_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid4_stamp |            2 | tid4        | A         |        5060 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| idevaff_iptracking |          1 | acct_id_tid4_stamp |            3 | stamp       | A         |     6775984 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
29 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You are selecting columns in an aggregation query that are not arguments to aggregation function nor are they group by keys.

Comment: For any performance related question, two things help: 1) `EXPLAIN` statement result 2) Table structure details (especially Indexing details)

Comment: Points made. Edited question and added explain, table structure, indexes...  Maybe I just don't see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this composite index:

```
INDEX(column2, column)
```

If that does not suffice, we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in order to discuss further.  (`geo_stamp_ip` is not as good.)

It is usually a mistake to splay an array (the `tid's`) across columns.

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ip) v, geo n
    from  idevaff_iptracking
    where  geo<>'XX'
      and  stamp between '1525122000' AND '1543615199'
    group by  n
    order by  v desc;
```

Some of the indexes are redundant.  In general, `INDEX(a)` can be removed if you have `INDEX(a,b)`.  (For example: `acct_id_ip`)

Comment: I think adding the column2, column index helped. Now it executes for about 10-11 seconds. Much, much better! Thank you for your input!! I thought adding geo_stamp_ip would be better to also satisfy the where condition but it looks like I have to recheck the indexes documentation of mysql... Again... Thanks!

Comment: @user3377238 - I'm glad it helped.  [_Here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) is my "cookbook on indexing" for novices.

Comment: Thanks! I know this page. Will check out again. What do you mean by "It is usually a mistake to splay an array (the tid's) across columns."? :)

Comment: @user3377238 - If, instead of 4 tid columns, you had a extra table with up to 4 (or even more) rows for the multiple tids, a lot of queries become simpler and possibly faster, in spite of doing `JOIN` to connect to the new table.

Comment: There is no JOIN for the tids columns.acct_id_tidX_stamp index is for a query that looks like  select COUNT(*) v,geo n from idevaff_iptracking where acct_id = $id  and stamp between '" . strtotime($startD . ' 00:00:00') . "' and '" . strtotime($endD . ' 23:59:59') . "' group by geo  order by v desc. I will try switching the place of tidX and stamp in these 4 indexes to see, if it would execute faster, as per your cookbook explanations.I also have similar queries instead of * with distinct(ip).Also CONCAT(tid1,' ',tid2, ' ',tid3, ' ',tid4) instead of tidX for displaying combination of all tids.

Comment: @user3377238 - When pulled from a separate table, it would be `GROUP_CONCAT(tid SEPARATOR ' ')`, optionally with an `ORDER BY`.  Also, `DISTINCT` is not a function; it is a qualifier on `SELECT/COUNT/GROUP_CONCAT` and applies to the combination of items listed.